# Laravel provide different result when using where condition with update

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, orm

**Condition 1:**

```
$update=Model::orWhere(..)->orWhere(..)->update([$updateField => "1"]);
if($update==1)
```

this return an integer value as 0 and 1 things works fine

**Condition 2:**

```
 $update=Model::where(..)->orWhere(..)->orWhere(..)->update([$updateField => "1"]);
 if($update==1)
```

Gives error

> Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection could not
>   be converted to int

Also tried

```
 Model:where(function($q) use(..) {
            return $q
                     ->where(..)
                     ->orWhere(..);
          })->where(..)->update([$updateField => "1"]);
```

Also returns an object rather integer while updating, facing strange response

from update function.

Here is the final state of code

```php
$updated=0;
$updated=ShipmentOrderPalletInfos::where('shipment_id',$request->shipment_id)->where("pallet_scan_code", $scan_id)->update([$updateField => "1"]);
if($updated!=1){
    $updated=ShipmentOrderPalletInfos::where('shipment_id',$request->shipment_id)->where("carton_scan_code", $scan_id)->update([$updateField => "1"]);
}
if( $updated==1){
```

Any Help would be great

Comment: can you add what's inside the `where()` ? and why do you `return $q` inside the function ?

Comment: @N69S just column and value if something  important i would have added

Comment: @N69S problem is added an extra `where` returns object not integer

Comment: Do you debugger the `$update` variable. Is that really collection? Because it works all fine to me, and you have a syntax error `Model:`, please fix it to `Model::`

Comment: @phpdroid your issue is not in the code you provided. you've omitted something important (other than the syntax error). please provide your code as is.

Comment: @TsaiKoga that was a typo in renaming model

Comment: @phpdroid i dont see the `orWhere` causing the issue in your final code and is it only the second condition (`$updated == 1`) causing an error ?

Comment: yes second condition @N69S found issue it was above this code sadly

Comment: @phpdroid 4 comments above "your issue is not in the code you provided. you've omitted something important"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please chnage your code

it is integer value

you give it form of string thats why give you error

```
update([$updateField => 1]);
```

or

```
$update=Model:where(..)->Where(..)->Where(..)->update([$updateField => 1]);
 if($update==1)
{
```

Comment: condition 1 working perfectly fine please go through it

Comment: error am getting from the variables i assigned this value to let me update question

Comment: @VikasKatariya that has nothing to do with the error, you can put a string `"1"` as value for an int field in database.

Comment: also i have query like `(a==1 || b==2) and c==3` not   `a==1 and b==2 and  c==3`

Comment: please give upvote this answer if this answer is helpful for you THANK YOU!!@phpdroid